# ModuleNotFound while running the web app locally

Tags: python, django, project

I'm trying to run the project available on GitHub locally as mentioned in the instructions but getting ModuleNotFound error even though I've cloned the whole project and following the instruction in a correct way as mentioned.

I'm unable to understand this. Please find the repository [here](https://github.com/aasis21/4th_umpire).

[image: This is the error message I'm getting while trying to run the server locally.]

Comment: did you install your requirements on the server? (probably not)

Comment: If my answer is solving your problem then mark it as best answer. Thank you if advance @vinay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common error when you are trying to import library that is not installed.
To fix this, you have to install library by:

```
pip install bootstrapform
```

Or install all requirements attached to project using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And then append it to list of your packages in django settings, in your project it is `4th_umpire/web/cfd/settings.py`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'bootstrapform',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'fourth_umpire',
'bootstrapform',
```

]

Comment: Actually I've done it already and it does exists on the path you have suggested but still I'm getting the same error, I don't know why.

Comment: I'm using macOS Mojave in case you need to know.

Comment: When I'm trying to install using the first command ( pip install bootstrapform ) in terminal, I am getting this error.     ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bootstrapform (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for bootstrapform

Comment: Second command includes first. So if second command works then everything is installed correctly. Are you sure that you are installing these packages inside virtual environment?

Comment: I think I'm. If not please tell me where to find the error because as the question is answered above, I've done the same already after activating virtual environment and that's what the repository tells. I've done the same process and settings.py does contains bootstrapform inside INSTALLED_APPS as mentioned above and still getting the same error. Although I'm using pip instead of pip3 as mentioned in the repository and to run the server locally I'm using// python3 manage.py runserver // as mentioned in the repository.

Comment: I tried using the command   python manage.py runserver then I'm getting a totally different error message which is:   File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax         and this altogether think is a different thing to look out for.